gzserver process has died followed by spawn_entity is frozen when calling service /spawn_entity
I am running ROS2 Humble and am unable to launch my robot arm when using the yaml file in my robot description files.  When I launch my gazebo.launch.py file, first I get an error telling me: "process has died [pid ####, exit code 255, cmd 'gzserver-slibgazeo_ros_inti.so -slibgazebo_ros_factory.so -slibgazebo_ros_force_system.so"].
Then, the launch appears to get hung-up on: [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity.
The files are located like this:
rad_ws
     |
     -agbot_controller
          |
          -agbot_arm_controllers.yaml
     |
     -agbot_description
          |
          -launch
               |
               -agbot_arm_gazebo.launch.py
          |
          -urdf
               |
               -agbot_arm_gazebo.xacro
               -agbot_arm_ros2_control.xacro
               -agbot_arm.urdf.xacro
               -common_properties.xacro

This is the printout from the command prompt:
$ ros2 launch agbot_description agbot_arm_gazebo.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/<name>/.ros/log/2024-08-05-15-12-33-847895-<name>-humble-46747
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [46774]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [46776]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [46778]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-4]: process started with pid [46780]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-5]: process started with pid [46782]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1722888757.807251488] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1722888757.809209275] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_plate
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1722888757.809238379] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment claw_support
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1722888757.809256654] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment forward_drive_arm
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1722888757.809272541] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment gripper_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1722888757.809287732] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment gripper_right
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1722888757.809302495] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment horizontal_arm
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1722888757.809317909] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment rgb_camera
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1722888757.809333502] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment rgb_camera_optical
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1722888757.809347551] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process has died [pid 46774, exit code 255, cmd 'gzserver -slibgazebo_ros_init.so -slibgazebo_ros_factory.so -slibgazebo_ros_force_system.so'].
[joint_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1722888758.440425625] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1722888758.529314499] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1722888758.529869639] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-5] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-5]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1722888758.532804003] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1722888758.545007329] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1722888758.546015708] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1722888758.555230062] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity

The process does not go beyond this point.  Below are the relevant files....
This is the urdf.xacro file...
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="agbot_arm">


    <xacro:property name = "forward_drive_arm_length" value = "1.00" />
    <xacro:property name = "forward_drive_arm_width" value = "0.26" />
    <xacro:property name = "forward_drive_arm_height" value = "0.02" />
    <xacro:property name = "horizontal_arm_length" value = "0.750" />
    <xacro:property name = "horizontal_arm_width" value = "0.26" />
    <xacro:property name = "horizontal_arm_height" value = "0.02" />  

    <!-- Include Gazebo Parameters -->
    <xacro:include filename="$(find agbot_description)/urdf/agbot_arm_gazebo.xacro" />

    <!-- Include ros2_control Plugins -->
    <xacro:include filename="$(find agbot_description)/urdf/agbot_arm_ros2_control.xacro" />

    <xacro:include filename="$(find agbot_description)/urdf/common_properties.xacro" />

    <!-- Useful XACRO Variables (Properties) -->
    <xacro:property name="PI" value="3.14159265359" />
    <xacro:property name="effort" value="30.0" />
    <xacro:property name="velocity" value="10.0" />
    <xacro:property name="scale" value="0.0075 0.0075 0.0075"/>

    <!-- Useful Macros -->
    <xacro:macro name="default_inertia" params="mass">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <mass value="${mass}" />
            <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
                     iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0"
                     izz="1.0" />
        </inertial>
    </xacro:macro>

    <xacro:macro name="default_transmission" params="name">
        <transmission name="${name}_transmission">
            <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
            <actuator name="{name}_motor" role="actuator1"/>
            <joint name="{name}_joint" role="joint1">
                <mechanical_reduction>1.0</mechanical_reduction>
            </joint>
        </transmission>
    </xacro:macro>

    <!-- Link Descriptions -->
    <link name="world"/>

    <link name="base_link">
        <xacro:default_inertia mass="1.0"/>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.35 -0.37 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/basement.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="blue"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="-0.35 -0.37 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/basement.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry> 
        </collision>      
    </link>

    <link name="base_plate">
        <xacro:default_inertia mass="0.1"/>
         <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.261 -0.295 -0.5" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/base_plate.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="red"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="-0.261 -0.295 -0.5" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/base_plate.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry> 
        </collision>
    </link>   

    <link name="forward_drive_arm">
        <xacro:default_inertia mass="0.1"/>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.01 -0.006 0.55" rpy="0 ${PI / 2} ${PI / 2}"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${forward_drive_arm_length} ${forward_drive_arm_width} ${forward_drive_arm_height}" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="yellow"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.01 0.006 0.55" rpy="0 -${PI / 2} ${PI / 2}"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${forward_drive_arm_length} ${forward_drive_arm_width} ${forward_drive_arm_height}" />
            </geometry> 
        </collision>
    </link>

    <link name="horizontal_arm">
        <xacro:default_inertia mass="0.1"/>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.1 0 0.37" rpy="0 ${PI / 2} ${PI / 2}"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${horizontal_arm_length} ${horizontal_arm_width} ${horizontal_arm_height}" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="green"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.1 0 0.37" rpy="0 ${PI / 2} ${PI / 2}"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${horizontal_arm_length} ${horizontal_arm_width} ${horizontal_arm_height}" />
            </geometry> 
        </collision>
    </link>   

    <link name="claw_support">
        <xacro:default_inertia mass="0.05"/>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-.1 0 0" rpy="0 -${PI/2} -${PI / 2}"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/claw_support.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="pink"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="-.1 0 0" rpy="0 -${PI/2} -${PI / 2}"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/claw_support.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry> 
        </collision>
    </link>    

    <link name="gripper_right">
        <xacro:default_inertia mass="0.01"/>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.078 0.005 0.36" rpy="0 ${PI / 2} ${PI / 2}"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/right_finger.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="purple"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.078 0.005 0.36" rpy="0 ${PI / 2} ${PI / 2}"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/right_finger.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry> 
        </collision>
    </link>

    <link name="gripper_left">
        <xacro:default_inertia mass="0.01"/>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.03 0.005 0.36" rpy="0 ${PI / 2} ${PI / 2}"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/left_finger.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="purple"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.03 0.005 0.36" rpy="0 ${PI / 2} ${PI / 2}"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/left_finger.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry> 
        </collision>
    </link>     

    <link name="rgb_camera_optical" >
    </link> 

    <link name="rgb_camera">
        <xacro:default_inertia mass="0.001"/>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.07 -0.105 0.095" rpy="0 ${PI/2} 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/pi_camera.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="blue"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="-0.07 -0.105 0.095" rpy="0 ${PI/2} 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find agbot_description)/meshes/pi_camera.STL" scale="${scale}"/>
            </geometry> 
        </collision>
    </link>

    <!-- Joint Descriptions -->
    <joint name="virtual_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="world"/>
        <child link="base_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 ${PI/2}"/>
    </joint> 

    <joint name ="base_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link = "base_plate"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.309"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit lower="-${PI}" upper="${PI}" 
               effort="${effort}" velocity="${velocity}"/>
    </joint> 

    <joint name="shoulder_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="base_plate"/>
        <child link="forward_drive_arm"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0.006 0.23" rpy="-2.0 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
        <limit lower="0" upper="4.0" effort="${effort}" velocity="${velocity}"/>
    </joint>    
    
    <joint name="elbow_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="forward_drive_arm"/>
        <child link="horizontal_arm"/>
        <origin xyz="0.27 0 1.07" rpy="-${PI} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
        <limit lower="-${PI}" upper="0" effort="${effort}" velocity="${velocity}"/>
    </joint>     

    <joint name="wrist_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="horizontal_arm"/>
        <child link="claw_support"/>
        <origin xyz="0.05 0 ${horizontal_arm_length}" /> 
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
        <limit lower="-${PI / 2}" upper="${PI / 2}" effort="${effort}" velocity="${velocity}"/>
    </joint>     

    <joint name="gripper_right_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="claw_support"/>
        <child link="gripper_right"/>
        <origin xyz="-.075 -.03 0.175"/> 
        <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
        <limit lower="-${PI / 2}" upper="0.0" effort="${effort}" velocity="${velocity}"/>
    </joint> 

    <joint name="gripper_left_joint" type="revolute">
        <mimic joint="gripper_right_joint" multiplier="-1"/> 
        <parent link="claw_support"/>
        <child link="gripper_left"/>
        <origin xyz="0.065 -.03 0.175"/> 
        <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
        <limit lower="0.0" upper="${PI / 2}" effort="${effort}" velocity="${velocity}"/>
    </joint>   

    <joint name="camera_optical_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="claw_support"/>
        <child link="rgb_camera_optical"/>
        <origin xyz = "0 .22 0.2" rpy = "0 0 0" />
    </joint> 

    <joint name = "rgb_camera_joint" type = "fixed" >        
        <parent link = "rgb_camera_optical" />
        <child link = "rgb_camera" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${PI/2} -${PI/2} -${PI/2}"/>
    </joint> 

 
    <xacro:default_transmission name="base_joint" />
    <xacro:default_transmission name="shoulder_joint" />
    <xacro:default_transmission name="elbow_joint" />
    <xacro:default_transmission name="wrist_joint" />
    <xacro:default_transmission name="gripper_right_joint" />


</robot>

This is the gazebo.xacro file...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="agbot_arm">

  <xacro:property name="PI" value="3.141592653589793238464" />

  <!-- Gazebo ros2_control plugin -->
  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
      <robot_param>robot_description</robot_param>
      <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
      <parameters>$(find agbot_arm_controller)/config/agbot_arm_controllers.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="rgb_camera">
    <sensor name="camera_sensor" type="camera">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
        <update_rate>60.0</update_rate>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so" name="camera_controller">
        <frame_name>rgb_camera_optical</frame_name>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>  

  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
  </gazebo>
    
  <gazebo reference="base_plate">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>
    
  <gazebo reference="forward_drive_arm">
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
  </gazebo> 
    
  <gazebo reference="horizontal_arm">
    <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
  </gazebo> 
    
  <gazebo reference="claw_support">
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
  </gazebo> 

  <gazebo reference="gripper_right">
    <material>Gazebo/Purple</material>
  </gazebo> 

  <gazebo reference="gripper_left">
    <material>Gazebo/Purple</material>
  </gazebo> 
  
  <gazebo reference="rgb_camera">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
  </gazebo>

</robot>

This is the control.xacro file...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="agbot_arm">

    <ros2_control name="RobotSystem" type="system">

        <xacro:property name="PI" value="3.14159265359" />

        <!-- ros2_control Gazebo -->
        <hardware>
            <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
            <param name="position_state_following_offset">0.0</param>
        </hardware>


        <joint name="base_joint">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">-${PI}</param>
                <param name="max">${PI}</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>      

        <joint name="shoulder_joint">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">0</param>
                <param name="max">4</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>      
        
        <joint name="elbow_joint">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">-${PI}</param>
                <param name="max">0</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>          

        <joint name="wrist_joint">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">-${PI/2}</param>
                <param name="max">${PI/2}</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>    
        
        <joint name="gripper_right_joint">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">-${PI/2}</param>
                <param name="max">0</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>   
        
        <joint name="gripper_left_joint">
            <param name="mimic">gripper_right_joint</param>  
            <param name="multiplier">-1</param>
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">0</param>
                <param name="max">${PI/2}</param>
            </command_interface>
        </joint>         

    </ros2_control>

</robot>

This is the controllers.yaml file...
controller_manager:
      
      ros__parameters:
        update_rate: 100 # Hz
    
        arm_controller:
          type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController
    
        gripper_controller:
          type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController
    
        joint_state_broadcaster:
          type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
    
    arm_controller:
      ros__parameters:
        joints:
          - base_joint
          - shoulder_joint
          - elbow_joint
          - wrist_joint
    
        command_interfaces:
          - position
    
        state_interfaces:
          - position
    
        open_loop_control: true
        allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true
    
    gripper_controller:
      ros__parameters:
        joints:
          - gripper_right_joint
          
        command_interfaces:
          - position
    
        state_interfaces:
          - position
    
        open_loop_control: true
        allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true

This is the common properties file.  It's just a bunch of colors for rviz to use.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <!-- Init colour -->
    <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="dark">
        <color rgba="0.3 0.3 0.3 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="light_black">
        <color rgba="0.4 0.4 0.4 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="blue">
        <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.8 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="green">
        <color rgba="0.0 0.8 0.0 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="grey">
        <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="orange">
        <color rgba="1.0 0.4235 0.0392 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="brown">
        <color rgba="0.8706 0.8118 0.7647 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="red">
        <color rgba="0.8 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="white">
        <color rgba="1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0"/>
    </material>  

    <material name="yellow">
        <color rgba="1.0 0.93 0.7 1" />
    </material>   
    
    <material name="purple">
        <color rgba="0.4 0.23 0.72 1" />
    </material>  

    <material name="turquoise" >
        <color rgba="0.05 0.737 0.690 1.0" />
    </material>  

    <material name="skyblue" >
        <color rgba="0.2 1.0 1.0" />
    </material>   
    
    <material name="pink" >
        <color rgba="1.0 0 1.0 1.0" />
    </material>        

</robot>

And this is the launch file...
    import os
from os import pathsep
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory, get_package_prefix

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription, SetEnvironmentVariable
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue


def generate_launch_description():
    
    agbot_arm_description = get_package_share_directory('agbot_description')
    agbot_arm_description_share = get_package_prefix('agbot_description')
    gazebo_ros_dir = get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros')
    
    model_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(name='model', default_value=os.path.join(
                                        agbot_arm_description, 'urdf', 'agbot_arm.urdf.xacro'
                                        ),
                                      description='Absolute path to robot urdf file'
    )    
    
    model_path = os.path.join(agbot_arm_description, "models")
    model_path += pathsep + os.path.join(agbot_arm_description_share, "share")
    
    env_var = SetEnvironmentVariable("GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH", model_path)    
   
    robot_description = ParameterValue(Command(['xacro ', LaunchConfiguration('model')]),
                                       value_type=str)
    
    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        parameters=[{"robot_description": robot_description},
                    {"use_sim_time": True}]
    )       
    
    joint_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package = 'joint_state_publisher',
        executable = 'joint_state_publisher',
        name = 'joint_state_publisher',
        parameters =[
            {'source_list':['joint_state_broadcaster/joint_states'],
             'rate' : 20.0
                }]
        )    
    
    world = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('agbot_description'),
        'worlds',
        'empty_world.world'
    )     
    
    start_gazebo_server = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            os.path.join(gazebo_ros_dir, 'launch', 'gzserver.launch.py')
        ),
        # launch_arguments={'world': world}.items()
    )    

    start_gazebo_client = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            os.path.join(gazebo_ros_dir, 'launch', 'gzclient.launch.py')
        )
    )
    
    spawn_robot = Node(package='gazebo_ros', 
                       executable='spawn_entity.py',
                       arguments=['-entity', 
                                  'agbot_arm', 
                                  '-topic', 
                                  'robot_description'
                                  ],
                       output='screen'
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        env_var,
        model_arg,       
        start_gazebo_server,
        start_gazebo_client,         
        robot_state_publisher_node, 
        joint_state_publisher_node,               
        spawn_robot
    ])

I have searched online for an answer, but nothing I try seems to work.  Oddly (?) when I comment out the line
"$(find agbot_arm_controller)/config/agbot_arm_controllers.yaml"
in the gazebo.xacro file, gazebo starts with the arm in the correct position and then gravity will make the robot arm collapse.  When I leave the yaml file in the gazebo.xacro file, gazebo starts, but the robot does not feel the effects of gravity.  This issue has been driving me nuts for a week now.  I would be extremely grateful to anyone who can help me with this!!  Thanks, in advance for any and all assistance.

ps -a

If your output is like this then there is a gazebo server running background:

Then you can kill the processes with:
kill -9 [pid]

Example:
kill -9 37443


That seems to have done the trick!!  THANKS!!!  I would have thought that [CTRL]-C would kill all the processes, but apparently not.

Usually they do, but sometimes it causes problems if it's not shutdown properly like in your case.
You're welcome...

Given that the answer solved your problem you can mark the answer as accepted if you want :)
